# Making a Login Work After Cache, Cookies, etc. Have Been Cleared

Tags: php

I am using the code below for a user login.  The first I try to login after cache / cookies, etc. have been cleared, the browser refreshes and the user name is not logged in.  After that, logging in works fine.

Any idea how I can make it work the first time?

Thanks in advance,

John

index.php:

```
   <?php 


        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){header('Location: http://www...com/.../index.php?username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'');} 



         require_once "header.php"; 
         include "login.php";
         require_once "footer.php";

        ?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
if (!isLoggedIn())
{
    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();


        } else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Login information !";
            show_loginform();
        }
    } else
    {

        show_loginform();
    }

} else
{

    show_userbox();


}



?>
```

show_loginform function:

```
function show_loginform($disabled = false)
{

    echo '<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'"> 

    <div class="usernameformtext"><label title="Username">Username: </label></div> 
    <div class="usernameformfield"><input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="30" id="username" /></div> 


    <div class="passwordformtext"><label title="Password">Password: </label></div> 
    <div class="passwordformfield"><input tabindex="2" accesskey="p" name="password" type="password" maxlength="15" id="password" /></div> 


    <div class="registertext"><a href="http://www...com/.../register.php" title="Register">Register</a></div> 
    <div class="lostpasswordtext"><a href="http://www...com/.../lostpassword.php" title="Lost Password">Lost password?</a></div> 

  <p class="loginbutton"><input tabindex="3" accesskey="l" type="submit" name="cmdlogin" value="Login" ';
    if ($disabled == true)
    {
        echo 'disabled="disabled"';
    }
    echo ' /></p></form>';


}
```

EDIT:  header.php includes this:

```
session_start();
```

So does that mean I'm using Sessions?

EDIT:  per webbiedave's request, here are the login credential check functions I'm using:

```
<?php

#### Login Functions #####


function isLoggedIn()
{

    if (session_is_registered('loginid') && session_is_registered('username'))
    {
        return true; // the user is loged in
    } else
    {
        return false; // not logged in
    }

    return false;

}

function checkLogin($u, $p)
{
global $seed; // global because $seed is declared in the header.php file

    if (!valid_username($u) || !valid_password($p) || !user_exists($u))
    {
        return false; // the name was not valid, or the password, or the username did not exist
    }

    //Now let us look for the user in the database.
    $query = sprintf("
        SELECT loginid 
        FROM login 
        WHERE 
        username = '%s' AND password = '%s' 
        AND disabled = 0 AND activated = 1 
        LIMIT 1;", mysql_real_escape_string($u), mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($p . $seed)));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    // If the database returns a 0 as result we know the login information is incorrect.
    // If the database returns a 1 as result we know  the login was correct and we proceed.
    // If the database returns a result > 1 there are multple users
    // with the same username and password, so the login will fail.
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 1)
    {
        return false;
    } else
    {
        // Login was successfull
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        // Save the user ID for use later
        $_SESSION['loginid'] = $row['loginid'];
        // Save the username for use later
        $_SESSION['username'] = $u;
        // Now we show the userbox
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you include the function that actually performs the credentials check and that sets the session/cookie?

Comment: Where is your session being started

Comment: Hi webbiedave, I included the credential check functions.  session_start(); is in header.php, which is included in index.php

Answer (score 0):

The line that is causing your page to refresh is

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){header('Location: http://www...com/.../index.php?username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'');}
```

What that is doing, is when you post to the page, it redirects you back to the index page with the username and password in the url.

> So does that mean I'm using Sessions?

Yes, you are using sessions.  That is how you are saving your login state from page to page.

However, to answer the question, remove the line I mentioned at the beginning of the article.  I cannot see where it does you any good.  It simply moves the values from the `$_POST` array to the `$_GET` array, and then you still look in the `$_POST` array.

**Edit:**

Change index.php to the following:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        header('Location: http://www...com/.../index.php');
    }
} 
require_once "header.php"; 
include "login.php";
require_once "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: The reason I want it there is so that the confirm submission pop-up doesn't appear when the user refreshes the browser.

Comment: ok.  Then confirm login before that line.  Then you don't have to pass anything via the URL.  Just don't print anything to screen if you are still redirecting using the header (redirect only if the login is successful).

Comment: Okay... that sounds like a promising idea.  Is it possible to put a redirect like that inside of a function?

Comment: You can put the redirect anywhere you want.  The only qualification is that you do not output anything to screen beforehand as that will cause an error to be thrown saying "headers already sent"

Comment: I tried putting if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']... inside the function show_userbox(); and it didn't solve the problem.  Any advice on where I should put it instead?

Comment: When I tried that, it said "Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkLogin()... on line 4"